# Selenium with proxy returns empty website

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I am having trouble getting a page source HTML out of a site with selenium through a proxy. Here is my code

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import codecs
import time

import shutil

proxy_username = 'myProxyUser'
proxy_password = 'myProxyPW'
port = '1080'
hostname = 'myProxyIP'

PROXY = proxy_username+":"+proxy_password+"@"+hostname+":"+port

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--kiosk")
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' %PROXY)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\kingOtto\Downloads\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe', options=options)

driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com")
time.sleep(10)
html = driver.page_source
f = codecs.open('dummy.html', "w", "utf-8")
f.write(html)

driver.close()
```

This results in a very incomplete HTML, showing only outer brackets of head and body:

```
html
Out[3]: '<html><head></head><body></body></html>'
```

Also the `dummy.html` file written to disk does not show any other content that what is displayed in the line above.

I am lost, here is what I tried

1. It does work when I run it without `options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' %PROXY)` line. So I am sure it is the proxy. But the proxy connection itself seems to be ok (I do not get any proxy connection erros - plus I do get the outer frame from the website, right? So the driver request gets through & back to me)
2. Different URLs: Not only whatismyip.com fails, also any other pages - tried different news outlets such as CNN or even google - virtually nothing comes back from any website, except for head and body brackets. It cannot be any javascript/iframe issue, right?
3. Different wait times (this article does *not* help: [Make Selenium wait 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347675/make-selenium-wait-10-seconds)), up to 60 seconds -- plus my connection is super fast, <1 second should be enough (in browser)

What am I getting wrong about the connection?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is because youre using an authenticated proxy.
In their documentation (https://www.browserstack.com/guide/set-proxy-in-selenium), it says:
"The best way to integrate authenticated proxies with Selenium is by using PhantomJS as a headless browser instead of the Chrome WebDriver."

Using an **unauthenticated** Proxy works like this

```
ChromeOptions options;
WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chromedriver.exe");

options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--proxy-server=ip:port");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("https://www.whatsmyip.org/");
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ip\"]")).getText());
```

this prints the ip set through the options.

Answer (score -1):

driver.page_source does not always return what you expect via selenium. It's likely NOT the full dom. This is documented in the selenium doc and in various SO answers, e.g.:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45247539/1387701

Selenium gives a best effort to provide the page source as it is fetched. Only highly dynamic pages this can often be limited in it's return.